# Exception: Undefined offset: 0 while making a get request in laravel 5.4 on AWS

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, amazon-ec2

getting Exception: Undefined offset: 0 while making a get request in laravel 5.4.

Not sure how to catch full error, i am pasting my code below:

Route :

```
Route::get('/merchants/create', function() {
    echo 'hellow';
});
```

instead of echoing hello

`Exception: Undefined offset: 0`

Web.php File:

```js
<?php

/*
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Web Routes
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |
  | Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
  | routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
  | contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
  |
 */





Route::get('/', function () {
return view('welcome');
});

  

Route::get('/merchants', 'MerchantsController@index');
Route::get('/merchants/{uuid}', 'MerchantsController@show');
Route::post('/merchants/{uuid}', 'MerchantsController@update');
Route::get('/merchants/create', function() {
    echo 'hellow';
});
```

Comment: The route has no issue and works fine. Check if you have some other code that's causing this. Share your full `web.php` code.

Comment: Please give the full exception and code.

Comment: Updated, All other routes are working well except the Route::get('/merchants/create', function() {
    echo 'hellow';
});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the Problem by Using this:

```
Route::get('/merchant/create', function() {
echo 'hellow';


});
```

Now sure what was the problem, just changed naming from **merchants** => **merchant**